# An algorithm in r about binomial random variables

Tags: r, random, simulation

I have the following algorithm (based on [this algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ7Wp.png))

1. Generate U
2. Define x=0,P=(1-p)^n and F=P
3. If U < F,then X=x and stop.
4. Define P=(n-x)*p*P/(x+1)(1-p), F=F+P and x=x+1
5. Come back to step 3.

According to my knowledge, on `r` would be

```
varBinom<-function(n,p)
{
  U<-runif(n)
  x<-0
  P<-(1-p)^n
  FF<-P

  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    if(U<FF)
    {
      X<-x
      break
    }
    P<-(n-x)*p*P/(x+1)*(1-p)
    FF<-FF+P
    x<-x+1
  }
  return(x)
}
```

However, when compiling the code, I get ten warning messages all of them say:

> Warning messages: 1: In if (U < FF) { :   the condition has length > 1
>   and only the first element will be used

Why does that happen?
How can I fix the code?

---

[image]

Comment: Well, you never seem to use `i` in your loop. That seems a bit odd. And `U` seems to be a vector, so it's unclear what you mean by `if(U<FF)` because it's possible that none, some, or all of the values in `U` are less than `FF` so it's not clear what you want. Perhaps you meant `if (U[i] < FF[i])`?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes that was what I had in mind, to treat U as an n vector so when calling the function the output would be n binomial random variables, but I guess can be fixed with the `set.seed(1) replicate(t, varBinom(n, p))` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made two little mistakes.

1. In 4 it should be P=(n-x) * p * P / **(**(x+1)*(1-p)**)** so (1-p) is in the denominator not in the numerator.
2. U is a one random number, but you create `n` different random numbers using `runif(n)`. This is also why you get the warning.

So here is the corrected algorithm:

```
varBinom<-function(n, p)
{
  U <- runif(1)
  x <- 0
  P <- (1-p)^n
  FF <- P

  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    if(U<FF) return(x)
    P <- (n-x) * p * P/((x+1)*(1-p))
    FF <- FF+P
    x <- x+1
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Here is the result when you call the function 15 times:

```
set.seed(1)
replicate(15, varBinom(10, 1/2))
[1] 4 4 5 7 4 7 7 6 6 3 4 4 6 5 6
```

Comment: Thank you. I compiled the code but always returns 10, why?

Comment: Odd, I added a piece of code on how to call this function. Is it possible that you have used `n= 10` and `p=1`?

Comment: No, I used `n=10` and `p=1/2` but I haven't seen you also modified `X<-x`, `break` by `return(x)` Why? Also, I think I did a mistake and should have been `return(X)` instead of `return(x)`

Comment: yeah you are right. Acctually you don't need `X`. `x` is enough.

Comment: Why the algorithm mentioned the existence of `X` then :)?

Comment: It is only the output value. You can either do X = x and return(X) or save one line of code and simply write return(x).